# How to set up geoprocessing tool and geoprocessing service to produce downloadable output in Web AppBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I want to create a simple application in ArcGIS Web AppBuilder which uses geoprocessing service to generate output file.

I have a simple Python script which generate a TIFF image from a complex map document. I created a script tool which successfuly generates an image.

My question is how to set up script tool parameters and geoprocessing service parameters to be able to configure geoprocessing widget in Web AppBuilder.   My intention is to have a download link as an output.

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at the help pages and download the configs for [Utility Map Generator](http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/gas/help/utility-map-generator/)--it allows the user to download a PDF though the GP widget in WAB.

Comment: @Paul, Thank for the tip. The examples mentioned gave me the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to set it up .
Here're the most important settings:

Script:
- output image is written to default scratch folder (`outDir = arcpy.env.scratchFolder`)
- script parameter: `arcpy.SetParameter(0,tif_path)`

Script tool:
- Parameter: Data Type - file; Type - Derived; Direction - Output

GP Service:
Default settings.

Web AppBuilder:
Geoprocessing widget's parameters are populated automatically after poining to the service.

Comment: So with these settings were you able to download the TIFF as output of GPservice in the Web AppBuilder?